# Roots of transcendental equation formed from determinant of a matrix containing bessel functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, determinants, transcendental-equation

I need to find roots of a transcendental equation formed by taking determinant of the following matrix. As you can see it is full of Bessel functions. I tired using the "fzero" command but it is not working.
All the bessel function inputs such as gamma and eta are function of beta.

```
A= [besselj(0,gamma1) -besselj(0,eta1*a/b) -bessely(0,eta1*a/b) 0 0 0 0;
    K1*besselj(1,gamma1) -besselj(1,eta1*a/b) -bessely(1,eta1*a/b) 0 0 0 0;
    0 besselj(0,eta1) bessely(0,eta1) -besselj(0,gamma2) -bessely(0,gamma2) 0 0;
    0 K2*besselj(1,eta1) K2*bessely(1,eta1) -besselj(1,gamma2) -bessely(1,gamma2) 0 0;
    0 0 0 besselj(0,gamma2*c/b) bessely(0,gamma2*c/b)  -besselj(0,eta2) -bessely(0, eta2); 
    0 0 0 K3*besselj(1,gamma2*c/b) K3*bessely(1,gamma2*c/b) -besselj(1,eta2) -bessely(1,eta2);
    0 0 0 0 0 besselj(1,eta2*d/c)-H*besselj(0,eta2*d/c), bessely(1,eta2*d/c)-H*bessely(0,eta2*d/c);];
```

Please let me know how to find value roots of thie subject transcendetal equation.
Thanks

Comment: "It is not working". Is it no working because someone broke your computer with an axe? Or is there some error? Is a higher power not letting your computer to solve the equations? Also, read MCVE help. It is a requirement in Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can try [fsolve from optimization toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) or try my [newtonraphson solver from FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html). Another option is [IPOPT](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt). I wrote a [blog post on using IPOPT with MATLAB](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2013/09/ipopt-as-non-linear-solver-for-matlab.html).